# maximizing linux raw socket throughput

Tags: linux, sockets

I have a simple application which receives packets of fixed ethertype via raw socket (the transport is ethernet), and sends two duplicates over another interface (via raw socket):

```
recvfrom() //blocking 
//make duplicate 
//add tail
sendto(packet1);
sendto(packet2);
```

I want two increase throughput. I need at least 4000 frames/second, can't change packet size. How can I achieve these? The system is embedded (AM335x SoC), kernel is 4.14.40... How can I encrease the performance?

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations:

1. I know you said you can't change "packet size", but using buffered writes and infrequent flushes might really help performance
2. You could enable jumbo frames
3. You could disable Nagle

Usually people don't want to change their packet sizes, because they expect a 1-to-1 correspondence between their send()'s and recv()'s.  This is not a good thing, because TCP specifically does not ensure that your send()'s and recv()'s will have a 1-1 correspondence.  They usually will be 1-1, but they are not *guaranteed* to do so.  Transmitting data with Nagle enabled or over many router hops or without Path MTU Discovery enabled makes the 1-1 relationship less likely.

So if you use buffering, and frame your data somehow (EG 1: terminate messages with a nul byte, if your data cannot otherwise have a nul or EG 2: transfer lengths as network shorts or something, so you know how much to read), you'll likely be killing two birds with one stone - that is, you'll get better speed and better reliability.

Comment: I know, raw sockets.  But this likely still applies.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Just to be more preсize, the transport layer is ethernet, no tcp or udp - socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(0x88ba)), so Nagle is not applicable here and one more thing is that the reciever expects fixed packet size and format (I can't modify receiver code), that is why I can't modify packet size

Comment: TCP and UDP can be done over ethernet, and indeed typically are. But you're right that raw sockets a different thing.  If the receiver is doing things based on the sizes of send's and recv's, that's a bug you should complain about.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... The thing is that the packet size is fixed by the standard (IEC61850), so I can't change it...

Comment: By the way how do you think how much throughput is possible to achive in my case (in frames per second) if I'm using 4.14 kernel on AM335x SoC?

Comment: Maybe I should use some kernel bypass techniques, like DPDK,PF_RING